# OdbcDataReader.GetValue(fieldNumber) returning empty string if the field value contains hyphen symbol

Tags: c#, .net, csv, odbcdatareader

I am trying to read data from csv file using `OdbcDataReader.GetValue(fieldNumber)`. For one of my csv file, there is a field for Social security number which contains hyphen. Sample value will be like 111-11-1111. The problem is when reading this value using `OdbcDataReader.GetValue(fieldNumber)`, I am getting empty string.

Here is my connectiom string

```
"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};dbg=;"
```

Anyone faced this before and have a solution? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When are you using a Text Driver with an ODBC DataReader.  The driver in the connection string has to be compatible with the class you are using to read data.

Comment: @jdweng, could you please be more specific? Do you mean changing the driver?

Comment: There are a least 3 different categories of drivers 1) ODBC 2) OLEDB 3) Microsoft Net Drivers.  They are not compatible.  You are using ODBC (OdbcDataReader) with the Microsoft Text Driver.